# New to Network Simulator 3

Tags: networking, wifi, simulation, ns-3

I recently started studying NS3, so I read the tutorial in the [website](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/index.html), but I'm having some problems.

For example I'm trying to create a small simulation where there are some nodes, using wifi, that move in the same direction at different speed (basically a road with some cars), but I found just some random models. Is there a model that can help me with that case (or must I change the position myself)?

Another one is the creation of a small protocol. Every node must send a certain message (a custom header with some extra fields) to the other nodes, but a node should read just the first message and reply, while it must ignore the other messages. How Should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to NS3 :)

A great place to start might be checking out the available examples in NS3 source files.

There is a "example" folder containing several scenarios in ns3 base directory. Also there are multiple examples for each module in "ns3/src/[module]/examples" directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMO (Simulation of Urban Mobility) tracefiles to create a vehicular movement. Then in your code include SUMO tracefile as shown below:

```
  #include "ns3/ns2-mobility-helper.h"
...
   std::string tracefile= "/home/mert/repos/vanet/highway_s/mobility.tcl";                
...
   // Create nodes and install mobility to all created nodes
   ueVeh.Create (numVeh);
   ueAllNodes.Add (ueVeh);

   Ns2MobilityHelper ns2 = Ns2MobilityHelper(tracefile);
   ns2.Install();
```

If you do not want to use SUMO then use scheduled periodic function which loads new positions to the nodes.

For the second question:
Filtering received packet is depended to your application. There are lots of examples in example directories and similar questions in ns3 googlegroups. If you specify your example then I can guide.